# Trying to get property of non-object "class-wp-query.php" and "link-template.php" in wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress, notice

I have a two PHP Notices at one of my project - **"Trying to get property of non-object"**

I know whats that means (more or less), but the problem is **i can't find** which code element make this notice... this drive me crazy...

1. Trying to get property of non-object in /xxxxxxxxxxxx/wp-includes/**class-wp-query.php** on line 3871

*( At github is here -> https://github.com/WordPress/WordPress/blob/master/wp-includes/class-wp-query.php#L4029 )*

2. Trying to get property of non-object in /xxxxxxxxxxxxxx/wp-includes/**link-template.php** on line 643

*( At github is here -> https://github.com/WordPress/WordPress/blob/master/wp-includes/link-template.php#L673 )*

In this project i used:

- My own template
- Woocommerce plugin (latest release)
- ACF (latest release)
- Yoast SEO (latest release)

Maybe is something wrong with my custom query?
For example this is what i use:

```
' https://pastebin.com/YEBQAXgs '
```

**The question is: how can i find/catch this notice and figure which part of my code should i correct?**

Comment: My research seems to suggest that it is Yoast that is the faulting code. When I disable Yoast the error goes away.

Answer (score 3):

It comes from Woocommerce wc_prevent_adjacent_posts_rel_link_wp_head function which is actioned by the template_redirect hook.

It does a call to is_singular('product') which gets the queried object and if the query is for a feed it comes back NULL and therefore is not an object.

Answer (score -1):

With what you posted, it’s probably a Symptom of an invalid sql query.  If you try to prepare bad sql, it won’t generate a statement object which will lead to that error.